# Why do I need to use `size_t` in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

As a beginner, I'm really confused about `size_t`. I can use `int`, `float` or other types. Why still declare `size_t` type. I don't feel its advantages.
I've viewed some [pages](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t), but I still can't understand it.

Comment: To confuse you even more, there is `ptrdiff_t`.

Comment: @Mayhem I have read this question, but still don't know what's the use of it

Comment: To confuse you even more: there's `size_t` (from `stddef.h`) and `std::size_t` (from `cstddef`).

Comment: It can hold bigger numbers than an `int` It is guaranteed by the standard to be able to hold a number as large as the largest possible object the library is capable of creating.

Comment: This is one of the sucky parts of C++.

Comment: @immibis: What is? That you have you apply some brainpower?

Comment: @Galik - I like that guarantee myself, and I'm curious what the precise reference section in the standard is - do you know?

Comment: @JohannGerell "**C++14 18.2 Types** (6) *The type size_t is an implementation-defined unsigned integer type that is large enough to contain the size
in bytes of any object.*"

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit The proliferation of integer types. The more types there are, the harder it is to make sure you don't accidentally convert one to another (potentially resulting in overflow). Someone mentioned that `list<string>::size_type` might be bigger than `size_t` for example.

Comment: You shouldn't convert `size_t` to `int` because `size_t` might be bigger. You shouldn't convert `int` to `size_t` because `int` might be bigger. Iterating over an array with a counter of type `int`, for example, is wrong. Your compiler also won't warn you as long as the sizes along on your platform.

Comment: @Galik: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37159141/why-do-i-need-to-use-size-t-in-c?noredirect=1#comment61859884_37159592

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Its main advantage is that it's the right tool for the job.**

`size_t` is literally defined to be big enough to represent the size of any object on your platform. The others are not. So, when you want to store the size of an object, *why would you use anything else*?

You can use `int` if you like, but you'll be deliberately choosing the inferior option that leads to bugs. I don't quite understand why you'd want to do so, but hey it's your code.

If you choose to use `float`, though, please tell us what program you're writing so we can avoid it. :)

Comment: Adding to this: A common example is a function taking an index into an array, `std::vector` or similar container. `size_t` is the type guaranteed to be large enough to express all values that could legitimately be a valid index into such a container.

Comment: Just to stir things up a little, note that strictly speaking you should use `vector<int>::size_type` as the type for the size for a vector. It doesn't *necessarily* have to be the same as `std::size_t`! Although for an easy life, just use `auto`.

Comment: Haha, I may be get it! Thanks! :)

Comment: @Bathsheba Strictly speaking, shouldn't `size_t` be greater than or equal to `vector<T>::size_type` on all platforms due to the fact that `vector` is contiguous?  For non-contiguous containers, I guess some very exotic implementations and memory architectures could *hypothetically* allow you to hold a number of objects greater than the total size in bytes of the largest theoretical object...

Comment: @Lightness Just curious - you don't happen to know the exact reference section in the standard for this guarantee definition?

Comment: @Johann _`[C++14: 18.2/6]:` The type `size_t` is an implementation-defined unsigned integer type that is large enough to contain the size in bytes of any object._

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: better If you ur last comment into answer. Why  you said that `float` data type should be avoided ?

Comment: @Destructor: Why would you use a floating-point value to represent the size of an object? I'll leave it up to you to ruminate on all the ways in which that's a poor idea.

Answer (score 4):

Using a `float` would be horrible since that would be a misuse of floating point types, plus type promotion would mean that multiplying the size of anything would take place in floating point!

Using a `int` would also be horrible since the specifics of an `int` are intentionally loosely defined by the C++ standard. (It could be as small as 16 bits).

But a `size_t` type is guaranteed to adequately represent the size of pretty much anything and *certainly* the sizes of containers in the C++ standard library. Its specific details are dependent on a particular platform and architecture. The fact that it's an *unsigned* type is the subject of much debate. (I personally believe it was a mistake to make it `unsigned` as it can mess up code using relational operators and introduce pernicious bugs that are difficult to spot).

Comment: `int is intentionally loosely defined by the C++ standard. (It could be as small as 16 bits)` Why?

Comment: I disagree with the unsigned = mistake part. The nature of sizes is that they cannot be negative. This is reflected nicely by using an unsigned type, additionally, you do not throw away half of the range of the data type (in the context that sizes cannot be negative).

Comment: @vpc Because it shall represent the data type that can be most efficiently processed on the hardware the code is intended to run on. And e. g. on a 16-bit processor, this would be a 16-bit data type...

Comment: @Bathsheba So, the actual value of `size_t` may change between different platform? Can I use `size_t` replace all other types(`int`, `float`, `double`, ... )

Comment: @KevinZhang: Yes, it (the range of the type) can change. No, you can't use it instead of _anything else_. Why are you trying to find a one-type-fits-all-solution? No such thing exists. Use the right tool for the job at hand.

Comment: @KevinZhang The width of the underlying type can change (e.g. on a 32-bit machine it will be a 32-bit integer, on a 64-bit machine it will be a 64-bit integer)

Comment: @Aconcagua OTOH, is the nature of sizes that they follow modular arithmetic?

Comment: @KevinZhang `size_t` is an integral data type - how should this one replace floating point data types? And if size_t is larger than int (can be the case on some exotic 16-bit machines), you would lose efficiency in any those cases where you can easily live with those 16 bits.

Comment: @juanchopanza: If it isn't, it also isn't their nature to have undefined overflow. I don't think you can base a theoretical argument here on the behaviour of unsigned arithmetic. A practical one? More likely.

Comment: @Bathsheba Thanks!

Comment: There is a separate (less known) signed `ptrdiff_t` type, for storing difference between pointers (number of elements between two positions in an array, for example).

Comment: @mindriot Detail about width of `size_t` and the width of the machine.  Although there is a tendency to correlate, the "width"  of the machine is the native processing width.  The width of `size_t` relates to the addressing space of the machine.  E.g. A 16-bit processor with 16-bit `int/unsigned`, yet a 32-bit `size_t` as its address space is much larger than 64k.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to use size_t whenever you want to store sizes of classes or structures or when you deal with raw memory(e.g. storing size of raw memory or using as an index of a raw array). However for indexing/iterating over standard containers (such as std::vector), I recommend using underlying size type of a given container(e.g. vector::size_type).